# IIS 8 overwriting response body when status codes indicate failure

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a WCF app running on Server 2008 w/ IIS 7.5 that does not have this issue, and then another instance running on Server 2012 w/ IIS 8 that does have this issue.  When my application sends a response body with a status code that indicates failure (400, 401, 500, etc), IIS will overwrite the response body that I set with this one (example):

```
{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

This is not an ASP.NET MVC application so I cannot use `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors`.

I've also tried setting the `system.webServer httpErrors` property with no luck.

Any idea how to change this so that I can control the response body like I do with Server 2008 and IIS 7.5 and not have it overwritten?  All of my responses are made by using `WebOperationContext.Current`.

Comment: Have you talked to system administrators if the firewall could "pollute" the body? some firewall products may even have default settings to "pollute" traffic.

Comment: Hi, the behavior happens on the local machine as well.  Just tried without the firewall and it made no difference.

Comment: I mean, Not your local Windows firewall, but your network firewall managed by system admin. Unless you have your own isolated environment without those server, and no network firewall in place.

Comment: Hi, I tried it on the local machine as well.  Same.

Comment: then check your IIS settings, particularly Handler Mappings to see if some of the handlers would rewrite the body. In fact, many handlers by default there are not needed for WCF service. If your WCF service is not sharing the Website (http listener) with other Website, you could safely remove many listeners. Google "wcf remove handler mappings iis" you will find a few good links, hopefully least handlers will kick out some possible offending handlers, and at least, you get better performance.

Comment: Just tried that, going all the way down to nothing but the svc-Integrated-4.0 *.svc handler.  Same behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59619/discussion-between-andy-h-and-haxor).